# Calculus Parcel Optimisation Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, derivatives, optimization

The question is worded as follows:

> "A courier firm has restrictions on the size of parcels that it will carry at the normal rate. The length of a parcel must be no less than twice its width. The sum of the length, width and height of any parcel also must be no more than 136 millimetres."

I thought I had solved this problem, I wrote an equation for the Volume, as well as a function graphing the width. Turns out I was way off and totally messed it up. I just can't understand how to solve this as the only way I can express $l$ seems to be with an inequality and I can't solve that. When I solved it first I tried: $l = 2w - x$

But I don't think that's correct. Any help would be appreciated. I'm also asked to provide an assumption which is made about the shape of the package.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Calling

$$
x = \mbox{length}\\
y = \mbox{width}\\
z = \mbox{height}
$$
the restrictions can be established as

$$
x \ge 0\\
y \ge 0\\
z \ge 0\\
x\ge 2 y\\
x+y + z \le 136
$$

resulting in the restriction volume attached

[image]

so the maximal feasible dimensions volume in one piece is

$$
x = \frac{544}{9}\\
y = \frac{272}{9}\\
z = \frac{136}{3}
$$

Assuming that the maximum volume fits tight we can proceed as follows

$$
V = x y z\\
x = 2y\Rightarrow V = 2y^2z\\
x+y+z = L\Rightarrow 3y + z = L\Rightarrow z = L - 3y\\
V = 2y^2(L-3y)
$$

so the extremum points obey

$$
\frac{d}{dy}V(y) = 4yL-18y^2=0\Rightarrow y = \frac{272}{9}
$$

etc.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it has to be done at a year 11 standard, using only a graphing calculator and algebraic working. The question is part of a calculus/differentiation unit so the answer will be attainable through finding an equation and solving its derivative equal to zero. The problem I'm having is how to deal with the inequalities as they don't allow for plotting as a function on the graphical calculator.

Comment: @afisc123 Attached a note I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks so much, it did.